# LPR: what is the location of the file that will be sent to the printer?

Tags: printing, epson, printer-control-language, lpr, spooler

For a research project about printing nanofluids I need some more control over my Epson Stylus SX600FW.
I am sending a file to the printer using `lpr test.ps`, then it is in the print queue. Now I want to see the file (in pdl?) that the printer driver will send to the printer. Where is the temp storage location of this file?

Or is there any other way to obtain this file? This file should contain ESC/P-R sequences in which I want to make some changes and then send that file to the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the URI `file:/tmp/ouput.prn`, and by configuring it with the (gimpprint) driver of your printer, you can obtain the output that is being sent to the printer.
This is a hexadecimal file. Using the parse-escp2 perl script from the test directory of gimp-print you can view this file in a bit more understandable format.